# creating a dataframe from nested dictionary of list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary of list which looks like:

```
dictionary = {'ss':{'feat1':[12,8173,9173,13],
                    'feat2':[73,1938,183,38]},
              'dd':{'feat1':[324,42,56,839],
                    'feat2':[13,398,817,9173]}}
```

I want to convert it to dataframe so that it looks like:

```
ss   feat1    12   8173. 9173.  13 
ss   feat2    73.  1938. 183.   38
dd   feat1    324.  42.  56.    839
dd   feat2    13   398.  817.  9173
```

How can I achieve this? Insights will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
dictionary = {
    "ss": {"feat1": [12, 8173, 9173, 13], "feat2": [73, 1938, 183, 38]},
    "dd": {"feat1": [324, 42, 56, 839], "feat2": [13, 398, 817, 9173]},
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)

dfe = df.explode(["ss", "dd"])
df_out = (
    dfe.set_index(dfe.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1, append=True)
    .unstack(0)
    .T.reset_index()
)

df_out
```

Output:

```
  level_0 level_1    1     2     3     4
0      ss   feat1   12  8173  9173    13
1      ss   feat2   73  1938   183    38
2      dd   feat1  324    42    56   839
3      dd   feat2   13   398   817  9173
```

Answer (score 1):

Try via `stack()`+`explode()`+`pivot()`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dictionary).stack().explode().reset_index()
df['key']=df.groupby(['level_0','level_1']).cumcount()
df=df.pivot(['level_1','level_0'],'key',0).reset_index()
df.columns=range(len(df.columns))
```

OR

via `stack()`+`explode()`+`unstack()`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dictionary).stack().explode()
df=(df.to_frame().set_index(df.groupby(level=[1,0]).cumcount(),append=True)
      .unstack().reset_index())
df.columns=range(len(df.columns))
```

output of `df`:

```
    0      1    2     3     4     5
0  dd  feat1  324    42    56   839
1  dd  feat2   13   398   817  9173
2  ss  feat1   12  8173  9173    13
3  ss  feat2   73  1938   183    38
```